# How to exit the Chromium search bar without using the mouse?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, chromium

On Linux Mint 17.2 I have chromium-browser installed. The shortcut `C-l` (Control + lowercase L) causes the address/search bar to be highlighted.

I would like to know if there's a shortcut or technique to exit it without pressing enter. Currently `C-f` with some small search term (that needs to exist on the page) with an `Esc` does the trick, but it feels like a hack.

Comment: Have you tried pressing `F6`? That seems to work for me on Google Chrome Version 44.0.2403.157 (64-bit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressing `F6` will remove focus from the url bar. It works for me in Google Chrome Version 44.0.2403.157 (64-bit) running on Lubuntu 14.04.